# select 10 rows per day with order

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a db with records with date (timestamp)
i need to select 10 records for each day (there are many more per day)
and order them by few columns...

how should that query look like?

Comment: Have you even tried to attempt a go?

Comment: I've spent more time than I'd like to admit trying to accomplish this in a single query, and I'm calling it quits. I would probably accomplish this by getting a list of distinct timestamps, and perform secondary queries in a loop. That said, this question really piqued my interest and I'll be watching it to see if a solution comes along. Thanks for giving me something to exercise my brain on.

Answer (score 4):

You have to get your 10 records per day in a subquery for each day and join them to the main table by a left join, so you'll get max 10 records per day. The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.columns
FROM mytable t1 
  LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT pk FROM mytable t2 
     WHERE t2.datecol = t1.datecol 
     ORDER BY t2.orderFor10Rows LIMIT 10) t3
  ON t1.pk = t3.pk
ORDER BY t1.anyOtherColumns
```

No warranty for proper MySQL-syntax as I'm not used to it.

Comment: Unknown column 't1.datecol' in 'where clause'

Comment: maybe right join?

Answer (score 4):

To select the top 10 records for each day ordered by days in SQL Server 2005

```
select * from 
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()
OVER
(PARTITION BY record.day order by record.day desc,record.score desc)
as row from record) 
as table1 where row < 11
```

Now since your record table doesn´t have a day column as such, you need to use something like `datepart(day, record.date)` instead of `record.day`

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

If you're working from a programming language and not directly querying the server, you could dynamically construct a query for the union of the 'Limit 10' or 'Top 10' for each day.  Not incredibly efficient, but it would at least work and be easy to debug and modify later.  You could even create the query dynamically via an SP in the server and work straight from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need ten rows — **any** ten rows, you don't care which, and there is no guarantee they're random, you can use the `LIMIT` clause. Example:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM tablename
  WHERE datecol = '2009-07-13'
  LIMIT 10
```

That'll give you ten rows. Its up to MySQL which ten. You can use `ORDER BY` or additional `WHERE` items to pick a certain 10. For example, here is the most recent 10:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM tablename
  WHERE datecol = '2009-07-13'
  ORDER BY timecol DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

`LIMIT` is documented as part of the [`SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: no, i need 10 rows for each day,

day 1 - 10 rows sorted by some column,
day 2 - 10 rows....

for all the data in db

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, but it will require a little work outside of sql. This is from a live example of a list of movies. All you need to do after this is pull the first 10 movies of the concatenated list.

```
SELECT Movie_Release_Year, GROUP_CONCAT( Movie_Title
ORDER BY Movie_Title ) 
FROM movies
GROUP BY Movie_Release_Year
```

see [Group Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more details

Answer (score 1):

After looking at (the ever excellent) xaprb blog from Baron Schwarz, http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/
I wonder if the use of user-defined variables could work here.

```
select hiredate, ename, sal
from ( select hiredate, ename, sal,
       @num := if(@hiredate = hiredate, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
       @hiredate := hiredate as dummy
     from emp_temp
) as x
where row_number < 3
order by hiredate, ename, sal
```

I've only tried the above for small sets of data, but it seems to work in bringing back just two records per hiredate. So far as I can tell from limited testing it should scale up for greater data sets. ( there may be performance issues in large data sets as Mysql is creating a temporary table)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it´s more like this, I had misplaced the order by for the date.

Here we assume there is a datetime field in the Records table and a score field to rank records.

```
SELECT      *
FROM            (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(year, Record.date), datepart(month, Record.date), datepart(day, Record.date)
ORDER BY Record.score desc) AS row
FROM            Record ) AS table1
WHERE        row < 11
ORDER BY datepart(year, Record.date) desc, datepart(month, Record.date) desc, datepart(day, Record.date) desc
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the elusive archaeologist's badge awaits.

Answer (score 1):

old question, but I found magnificient answer ( not my own ) using session variables.

Considering table

```
CREATE TABLE `report` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reportDate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`parameter` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `INDEX1` (`reportDate`,`parameter`,`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Following query will select top 10 parameter per day based on their counts on that day

```
SELECT parameter, reportDate, count
FROM
    (SELECT parameter, 
             reportDate, 
             count, 
             @reportDate_rank := IF(@current_reportDate = reportDate,@reportDate_rank + 1, 1) AS reportDate_rank,
             @current_reportDate := reportDate 
    FROM report
    ORDER BY reportDate, count DESC
    ) dateRanked
WHERE reportDate_rank <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MySQL, and the column is of type timestamp.
You need to convert it to Date and then compare it with the date you want to compare with.

> SELECT * FROM tablename tName
>
> where
>
> Date(timestampFieldName) = Date('2009-07-08')
>
> limit 0,10

Comment: i need a breakdown of days with 10 records from each, not for 1 date and limit of 10

Comment: What you want is possible with sub query but sub query in mySql dose not support limit.

Comment: Sub-queries in MySQL support limit; this works just fine (in 5.0 at least): select * from (SELECT whatever   FROM t   WHERE datecol = '2009-07-03'   LIMIT 10) t

Comment: OK. then solution below will work Bu I am using MySQL version 5.0.37 and got error code. 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Sounds like maybe MySQL supports LIMIT in certain subqueries, but not others.