# SQL query for Top 5 of every category

Tags: sql

I have a table that has three columns: Category, Timestamp and Value.

What I want is a SQL select that will give me the 5 most recent values of each category. How would I go about and do that?

I tried this:

```
select
  a."Category",
  b."Timestamp",
  b."Value"
from
(select "Category" from "Table" group by "Category" order by "Category") a,
(select a."Category", c."Timestamp", c."Value" from "Table" c
where c."Category" = a."Category" limit 5) b
```

Unfortunately, it won't allow it because "subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level".

I'm using PostGreSQL 8.3, by the way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146913/select-10-rows-per-day-with-order/1174434#1174434

Comment: There are n categories @hobodave

Comment: I am not oversimplifying. There could be any number of categories, from 3 to 30000.

Comment: You want to get them all in the same query?  In any order, or some particular order?

Comment: @hobodave, sorry, let me rephrase: You want to get the 5 most recent from all categories in the same query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.category, t1.timestamp, t1.value, COUNT(*) as latest
FROM foo t1
JOIN foo t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.timestamp <= t2.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.category, t1.timestamp
HAVING latest <= 5;
```

**Note:** Try this out and see if it performs suitably for your needs. It *will not scale* well for large groups.

Comment: Thank you so much. Performance fortunately is not of the essence here, so that does all I need. Thank you! :-)